# Node.js how to keep connection between page loads

Tags: javascript, node.js

On my website I have a list of all online users, updated in real-time by node.js (I'm using now.js)

The problem is, when a user navigates my site, they of course disconnect for a couple of seconds when the new page is loading. Which means they disappear from the list for all other clients, to pop back in just seconds later.

Is there any way to set a timeout on the disconnect function, e.g. if user has not reconnected in 30 seconds, remove from the list otherwise don't?

Or if there is a better way to accomplish this? Can someone please point me in the right direction :)

**EDIT:**

Came up with a working solution, if anyone would like to know. On server side I have this function

```
nowjs.on('disconnect', function() {
    everyone.now.clientDisconnected();
});
```

which whenever a user disconnects calls this function on the client

```
now.clientDisconnected = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { now.serverUpdateUsers(); }, 20000);
}
```

So instead of updating the users right away, we wait 20 seconds. By then the user should have finished loading the new page, and no difference will show for all other clients.

The `serverUpdateUsers();` is the serverside function that gathers all user data and pushes it out to all clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you can modify Socket.IO's settings with now.js (which uses Socket.IO), but if you could (not sure, never used now.js) you should set the heartbeat interval to be bigger:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

heartbeat interval defaults to 20 seconds

Comment: Yes, maybe a good idea.. But I don't really know how they interact. Came up with a simple solution above... Perhaps not optimal, but it works